Split multiple tables from a single sheet in excel using data flows
Need to extract data from multiple tables which are located in the same worksheet in an excel(.xlsx) file. Every table has a distinct header above the column names and every table ends with the row "total" (total row is not needed). There are currently 3 tables I need from this file but there will be a 4th table added in the future which needs to be extracted as well. I have the header and the column names for that table as well. The cell ranges are not fixed and the rows can increase or decrease in the next file so the tables need to be picked up dynamically.
The output needs to be one big table which contains all the distinct columns from all the 3 tables and the columns from the 4th table as and when it is avaiable in the source file.
I am trying on Data flows but not able to extract the tables. I am open to working on ADF or Synapse also if there is a solution.
The sample input is shown below(All tables are in the same sheet):



Trial Balance








Acc Number
Original Balance
Current Balance
Interest Rate
Original Date


546172
2354673
231473
10%
07-03-2023


758682
2375764
137487
9%
09-09-2020


536357
6473635
474661
13%
11-05-2022


Total
658496
784651








Delinquency Report







Acc Number
Original Balance
Current Balance
Next Due Date


546172
2354673
231473
07-03-2024


536357
6473635
474661
09-09-2024


758682
2375764
137487
11-05-2024


Total
658496
784651





If you know the cell range for each table you can do.

@JayashankarGS I know the cell ranges but they might change in the future so the process needs to pick up the tables dynamically

You can use synapse notebook with pandas functionality to combine all of you tables.
Below i am giving an example for 2 tables in you excel file similarly you alter below code for more tables.
df = pd.read_excel("https://vjgsblob.blob.core.windows.net/data/csvs/extracted_data.xlsx?sp=r&st=2024-09-13T07:07:11Z&se=2024-09-13T15:07:11Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=2AmroznyDPtH5boSZym8yxpLibsD0X4te18Phj%2BpAxc%3D").dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = [f'col{i}' for i,j in enumerate(df.columns)]

# Getting the column names where table name indicator presents
trialBalancCol = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].str.contains('Trial Balance', na=False).any()][0]
deliquencyReportCol = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].str.contains('Deliquency Report', na=False).any()][0]

# Getting the position, which is used to split them.
trialBalance = df[df[trialBalancCol]=='Trial Balance'].index[0]
deliquencyReport = df[df[deliquencyReportCol]=='Deliquency Report'].index[0]
print(trialBalance,deliquencyReport)

#splitting the tables

dfTrialBalance = df[(df.index>trialBalance) & (df.index<deliquencyReport)].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
dfDeliquencyReport = df[df.index>deliquencyReport].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')

#Removing total row
totalCol = [col for col in dfTrialBalance.columns if dfTrialBalance[col].str.contains('total', na=False).any()][0]
dfTrialBalance = dfTrialBalance[df[totalCol]!='total']
totalCol = [col for col in dfDeliquencyReport.columns if dfDeliquencyReport[col].str.contains('total', na=False).any()][0]
dfDeliquencyReport = dfDeliquencyReport[df[totalCol]!='total']

# Creating the column names
dfTrialBalance.columns =  dfTrialBalance.head(1).values.flatten().tolist()
dfDeliquencyReport.columns =  dfDeliquencyReport.head(1).values.flatten().tolist()

#Removing the column name row and resetting the index
dfTrialBalance = dfTrialBalance.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
dfDeliquencyReport = dfDeliquencyReport.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

#Joining the tables
ResTable = pd.merge(dfTrialBalance,dfDeliquencyReport,on='Acc Number',how='left')
ResTable

After executing all above code you save it back to storage account in csv format(ResTable.to_csv(<path>)).
Again, alter this code according to your data.
Input :

Output:



Acc Number
Original Bal
Current Bal
Interest rate
Original Date
Original Balance
Current Balance
Next Due Date





546172
2354673
231473
0.1
2023-07-03 00:00:00
2354673
231473
2024-07-03 00:00:00



758682
2375764
137487
0.09
2020-09-09 00:00:00
NaN
NaN
NaN



536357
6473635
474661
0.13
2022-11-05 00:00:00
6473635
474661
2024-09-09 00:00:00





Thank you so much @JayashankarGS. I used com.crealytics.spark.excel to load the file since I am using abfss method with parameters but did the transformations using pandas using your instructions. Worked like a charm :)
